# Series of Multiple Actions in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am just trying to enter a text in capital letters using set of keyboard actions. Here code using interface 'Action':

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("email")); 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Action act = builder.moveToElement(element)
                    .keyDown(element,Keys.SHIFT)
                    .sendKeys("vishal")
                    .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
                    .build();
act.perform();
```

Above is working fine.

But if we do not use interface, it is not working why ??? Though this is executing fine but not performing the task. I think both should work.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("email")); 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element)
       .keyDown(element,Keys.SHIFT)
       .sendKeys("vishal")
       .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
       .build();
builder.perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, it's because you're calling **build()** then **perform()**

If you look at the Actions class implementations of those two methods:

```
  /**
   * Generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to be performed (and
   * resets the internal builder state, so subsequent calls to build() will contain fresh
   * sequences).
   *
   * @return the composite action
   */
  public Action build() {
    CompositeAction toReturn = action;
    resetCompositeAction();
    return toReturn;
  }

  /**
   * A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first.
   */
  public void perform() {
    build().perform();
  }
```

When you call **build()** it actually resets the internal state of the builder!

After that when you call **perform()** it rebuilds an empty object reference which has no behavior defined.

To correct the problem, I suggest replacing your call to **build()** with a call to **perform()** as shown below.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("email")); 
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
 builder.moveToElement(element).keyDown(element, Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("vishal").keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

I would expect that to do what you want, based on the implementation.

> My investigation was done against selenium v 2.53.0

Answer (score 0):

Because `Actions#build()` method resets a state of itself before returning the action,
see the implementation here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.18.0/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.java#Actions.build%28%29

```
338
339  public Action More ...build() {
340    CompositeAction toReturn = action;
341    resetCompositeAction();
342    return toReturn;
343  }
```

Pay attention to `resetCompositeAction();` call - it resets the builder.

If you perform this:

```
 builder............
        ........ ().build();
builder.perform();
```

Then `build()` returns the action and resets a state of `builder` object.
 Then if you call `builder.perform()`, it's do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.moveToElement(element)
       .keyDown(element,Keys.SHIFT)
       .sendKeys("vishal")
       .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT)
       .build().perform();
```